# TKinter weird behavior using grid location manager with arguments row=0, column=0

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

I'm using two frames to organize my main frame into two subframes.
One subframe is one the left and it contains a few buttons and a label. The subframe on the right contains a treeview.

The items in the left_frame don't show up when I use the arguments row=0, column=0 as show in the example below.

```
class MainFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

        # containers
        self.left_frame = ttk.Frame() # contains all the buttons and icons on the left
        self.left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.right_frame = ttk.Frame() # contains the spreadsheet preview
        self.right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)

        # labels
        self.label = ttk.Label(self.left_frame, text="Platzhalter für Icon")
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # buttons
        self.analyse_button = ttk.Button(self.left_frame, text="auswählen")
        self.analyse_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.analyse_button = ttk.Button(self.left_frame, text="importieren")
        self.analyse_button.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.rate_button = ttk.Button(self.left_frame, text="bewerten")
        self.rate_button.grid(row=3, column=0)

        self.rate_button1 = ttk.Button(self.left_frame, text="analysieren")
        self.rate_button1.grid(row=4, column=0)

        # treeview widget for spreadsheets
        self.sp_preview = ttk.Treeview(self.right_frame)
        self.sp_preview.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

If I change the code as below

```
self.left_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)
self.right_frame.grid(row=0, column=2)
```

it works as intended. But that feels wrong, because I'm not using column 0.

Comment: How do you put the instance of `MainFrame` in the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely because you did not specify the parent of `left_frame` and `right_frame`, so they will be children of root window, not instance of `MainFrame`.

If instance of `MainFrame` or other frame is also a child of root window and put in row 0 and column 0 as well, it may overlap/cover `left_frame`.

Set the parent of the two frames to `self` may fix the issue:

```py
class MainFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

        # containers
        self.left_frame = ttk.Frame(self) # contains all the buttons and icons on the left
        self.left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.right_frame = ttk.Frame(self) # contains the spreadsheet preview
        self.right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)

        ...
```